# What is a role of plus in front of a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a code that looks like following

```rb
value = +"#{x}/part"
value << "/part2"
```

I understand that value would contain something like `valueOfX/part/part2`, but I don't understand why there is + in front of the string. I tried searching for it, but search engines are not very good at understanding what "plus in front of a string ruby" means. I also tried to run this in online ruby repl with no difference when + is added or not added.

So question is why may it be useful to have + like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If the string is frozen, then return duplicated mutable string.
>
> If the string is not frozen, then return the string itself.

source: https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2B-40

So in your case, since your string is not frozen, your code is equivalent to:

```
value = "#{x}/part"
```

**EDIT:**

As explained by @stefan in the comments, in Ruby 2.x, interpolated string were frozen with `frozen_string_literal: true`. So `value = +"#{x}/part"` is not equivalent to `value = "#{x}/part"`. It's not the case anymore with Ruby 3.

Comment: _"since your string is not frozen"_ – you can't know for sure. In Ruby 2.x with `frozen_string_literal: true` it would be frozen and the OP's second line would raise a `FrozenError`

Comment: Since there is a variable interpolation, the string is not frozen.

Comment: (even if the `x` variable has been declared just before with a String (like `x = "s"`) and is frozen)

Comment: Ruby 2.x freezes strings containing interpolation. That behavior [changed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17104) with Ruby 3.0.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info :-o I'll update my answer